# Specify Horizontal and Vertical Movement

Tags: vb.net, delimited, textfieldparser

I'm looking to be able to move through a pipe ("|") delimited text file, controlling both the row and column I read.

I have previously achieved this in MS Access VBA and am currently starting to in VB.NET, but struggling to complete this.

In Access, VBA allowed me to link to the text file as a recordset (`Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`), pre-defined as delimited and move through rows (`rs.MoveNext` or `rs.MovePrevious`) whilst selecting the fields/columns I required (`rs!Field1`).

Is there any equivalent in VB.NET? so far I have only been able to find the following from MSDN, but don't know how to manipulate it:

```
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(FName)

        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters("|")
        Dim currentrow As String()

        While Not MyReader.EndOfData

            currentrow = MyReader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentfield As String
            For Each currentfield In currentrow
                MsgBox(currentfield)
            Next

        End While

    End Using
```

I want to be able to store certain fields to variables to be written to .CSV files later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone whom this may help, I managed to resolve this with the help the of the two following websites:

[Loop Through Files in Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss(v=vs.90)?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)

[Delimit Data](https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet)

Using these I created the following button click sub and accompanying function:

```
Private Sub Button_Run_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Run.Click

    ' Make a reference to a directory
    Dim strDir As String = ("C:\")
    Dim Dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strDir)

    ' Get a reference to each file in that directory
    Dim fiArr As System.IO.FileInfo() = Dir.GetFiles()

    Dim fri As System.IO.FileInfo

    'For each file call the formatter to write to a text file
    'Then delete each file after writing it
    For Each fri In fiArr
        Call Formatter(strDir & fri.Name)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(strDir & fri.Name)
    Next fri

End Sub
```

Then I split each line by the delimiter where each field can be obtained (using the `values(0)` variable defined), and modified  (using it's index). Controlling the line is as simple as creating a new variable using or modifying existing variable by changing the `i` integer. E.g:

```
Dim Nvalues() As String = lines(i + 1).Split("|")
```

Using this I created the following function:

```
Public Sub Formatter(ByVal FName As String)

    'Standard start defining stream reader to loop
    'through and pull data from text files
    'FName is provided from the form button sub
    Dim StrReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FName)

    Dim text As String = StrReader.ReadToEnd

    StrReader.Close()

    Dim lines() As String = text.Split(vbLf)

    'Define all variables that may need to be stored before writing
    Dim x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x0 As String

    'Define where the data will be written to (line by line)
    Dim FPath As String = "C:\Sample.txt"
    If Not System.IO.File.Exists(FPath) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(FPath).Dispose()
    End If
    Dim objwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter

    'Set loop to go through all data from beginning to end using i as line index
    Dim i As Double
    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1

        'Split each line by pipes (|) allowing "values" to be indexed to pull by column
        Dim values() As String = lines(i).Split("|")

        'Set 1st column in row as switch item
        Select Case values(0)

            'If 1st column in row is 001, store required data in variables
            'specified using the index of the value to give accurate column
            Case "001"
                x1 = values(1)
                x2 = values(2)
                x3 = values(3)
                x3 = values(4)

                'Repeat same as 001 but for 002
            Case "002"
                x4 = values(1)
                x5 = values(2)

                'Repeat same as 001 but for 003
            Case "003"
                x6 = values(1)
                x7 = values(2)

                'Write to file including fields 1 & 3 from 004 group
            Case "004"

                objwriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(FPath)
                objwriter.WriteLine(x1 & "," & x2 & "," & x3 & "," & x4 _
                    & "," & x5 & "," & x6 & "," & x7 & "," _
                    & Nvalues(1) & "," & Nvalues(2))
                objwriter.Close()

            Case Else

        End Select

        Application.DoEvents()

    Next

End Sub
```